# ASP.NET Core Web Api Error for IhttpActionResult

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to create a new Core Web API app for the first time. I am using Core 2.2

I did some research but did not find the correct answer. Not sure if I am using wrong libraries.

cannot implicitly convert type microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okresult to system.web.http.Ihttpactionresult

Here is my Code

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/User")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllUsers()
    {
        var users = await this.GetUserAsync();
        return this.Ok(users);
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, remove the `System.Web` dependency. That's going to cause all sorts of issues. ASP.NET Core does not use `System.Web` so if you see something coming from that namespace, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `IActionResult`, not `IHttpActionResult`.

The `IHttpActionResult` interface does not exist in Core, it's used in older Web API projects.

Answer (score 3):

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllUsers()
{
    var users = await this.GetUserAsync()
    return Ok(users);
}
```

Try changing the type to IActionResult.
[According to Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.2): the following components don't exist in ASP.NET Core:

`IHttpActionResult` interface

And I don't believe you need this.Ok, it should be fine using just Ok.