# reactjs with core 3.1 api controller. Getting json error instead of returning data

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a login form and trying to get data back for session state. I'm getting the error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" If I do response.text() instead of response.json() I see it is returning the HTML page syntax. I am now able to get the data from the API but when I try to get it from the client I get the same error stated above.  If someone can please show me what I'm doing wrong because I've spent the last couple of days trying to get this to work and have been unsuccessful. It must be my fetch it won't return json. If someone can please help me I'd appreciate it.

`Login.js file`

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { Header } from './Header';
    
        class Login extends Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
    
                this.state = { fields: { "idAccount": 0, "idAccountUser": 0, "UserFirstName": "", 
        "UserLastName": "", "UserEmail": "", "UserCulture": "", "AllowContentDistribution": false }, 
        errors: {} };
                this.state = { inputFields: { "userName": "", "password": "" } };
    
            }
    
        authenticateUser(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var userName = e.userName;
            var password = e.password;
    
            if (this.handleValidation()) {
    
                fetch("Http://localhost:1234/api/CustomerManager/AuthenticateUser?UserName=" + userName + 
        "&Password=" + password, {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        accept: 'application/json'
                    },
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        response.json();
                    })
                    .then((data) => {
                        this.state.fields = data;
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log("idAccount: {0}, UserFirstName: {1}, UserLastName: {2}", 
        this.state.fields["idAccount"], this.state.fields["UserFirstName"], 
        this.state.fields["UserLastName"]);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log('error: ' + error);
                    });
            }
            else {
                console.log('error: ' + this.state.errors);
            }
        };
    
        handleValidation() {
            let fields = this.state.inputFields;
            let errors = {};
            let formIsValid = true;
    
            //UserName
            if (!fields["userName"]) {
                formIsValid = false;
                errors["userName"] = "UserName Cannot be empty";
            }
    
            //Password
            if (!fields["password"]) {
                formIsValid = false;
                errors["password"] = "Password Cannot be empty";
            }
    
            this.setState({ errors: errors });
            return formIsValid;
        };
    
         handleChange(field, e) {
            let fields = this.state.inputFields;
            fields[field] = e.target.value;
            this.setState({ fields });
        };
    
            render() {
            
                return (
                    <>
                        <Header />
                    <div className="login center">
                        <form
                                onSubmit={this.authenticateUser.bind(this)}
                        >
                            <div>
                                <label htmlFor="userName">
                                Username:
                            
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input
                                        id="userName"
                                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "userName")} value= 
       {this.state.inputFields["userName"]}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label htmlFor="password">
                                Password (case-sensitive):
                            
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input
                                    id="password"
                                        type="password"
                                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "password")} value= 
       {this.state.inputFields["password"]}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button className="Button ActionButton">Sign In</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                        </>
                );
            };
        }
    
        export default Login
```

`Controller`

```
    

    [HttpGet]
            public IHttpActionResult AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password)
            {
                try
                {
                    Login.AuthenticateUser(userName, password);
    
                    SessionState sessionState = new SessionState
                    {
                        IdAccount = IdAccount,
                        IdAccountUser = IdAccountUser,
                        UserFirstName = UserFirstName,
                        UserLastName = UserLastName,
                        UserEmail = UserEmail,
                        UserCulture = UserCulture,
                    };
    
                    return Ok(sessionState);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // show the error
                    return InternalServerError(ex);
                }
    
            }
```

Comment: Can you visit your API endpoint in the browser, and check the response is JSON and not XML.

Comment: How do you do that when the API endpoint is in the same project as the React Application?  I don't know how to do that.  I'm using VS 2019

Comment: Visit your `/api/CustomerManager/AuthenticateUser?UserName=xxx&Password=xxx` enppint in the browser. Prepend with http://localhost:port/

Comment: I don't get anything back.  I looked at the dev tools to see the request header of the request and it doesn't have json as one of the options. this is what it has. text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9

Comment: you have 2 state objects inside your constructor, the second  state assignment overrides the first assignment

Comment: Thank you I corrected that but I'm still getting the same error.  I noticed that the response Content-type is text/Html.  Could that be why I'm getting that error? If so, how do I correct it?

Comment: in authenticateUser funtion, 'e' does not contain the password and username values. You should better retrieve them from state. This "this.state.fields = data;" is also wrong because you are mutating the state directly, you must use setState to set your data into your state.

Comment: and fetch should not be assigned to a const.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-carson-3tx7l?file=/src/App.js i made a sandbox with the solution using a dummy endpoint. Delete the dummy url and and uncomment  your endpoint and it should work. You may also need to pass a baseUrl for your endpoint to work!

Comment: Thank you for pointing those errors out to me.  I've fixed them but am still getting the json error.

Comment: @get2dachoppa I modified my code to what you had in the sandbox and I'm still getting the same error. I changed the response to response.text() and this is what I got.  "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang=\"en\">\r\n<head>\r\n    <me…=\"/index.209172dd.js\"></script>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>"}  Which is why I think I'm getting the json error.

Answer (score 0):

Basically， the issue comes from the response type, and I tested in my side and id really worked. There's some error in your `login.js` but it isn't related to your error.

Per my searching, I found `IHttpActionResult` is an interface which is not [existed in Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55029270), you need to use `IActionResult` if your web api project is in asp.net core. I also recommend to use asp.net core rather than asp.net. By the way, if you still can't get json response, you may refer to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0#specify-a-format) to add filter `[Produces("application/json")]` on your method.

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { fields: { "idAccount": 0, "idAccountUser": 0, "UserFirstName": "", 
                                "UserLastName": "", "UserEmail": "", "UserCulture": "", "AllowContentDistribution": false 
                            }, 
                        errors: {} ,
                        inputFields: { "userName": "", "password": "" } 
                    };
    }

authenticateUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userName = this.state.inputFields.userName;
    var password = this.state.inputFields.password;

    const res = fetch("https://localhost:44325/api/CustomerManager/AuthenticateUser?UserName=" + userName + "&Password=" + password, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            accept: 'application/json'
        },
    })
    .then(res =>res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("msg is :"+data.msg);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error: ' + error);
    });
};

handleChange(field, e) {
    let fields = this.state.inputFields;
    fields[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ fields });
};

    render() {
    
        return (
            <>
                {/* <Header /> */}
            <div className="login center">
                <form
                        onSubmit={this.authenticateUser.bind(this)}
                >
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="userName">
                        Username:
                    
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input
                                id="userName"
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "userName")} value= 
{this.state.inputFields["userName"]}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="password">
                        Password (case-sensitive):
                    
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input
                            id="password"
                                type="password"
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "password")} value= 
{this.state.inputFields["password"]}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button className="Button ActionButton">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                </>
        );
    };
}
export default Login
```

Here's my controller, in asp.net core3.1:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace test0715.Controllers
{
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        [Route("/api/CustomerManager/AuthenticateUser")]
        public IActionResult Index(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            SessionState ss = new SessionState
            {
                age = 18,
                name = "test"
            };
            return Ok(ss);
        }
    }

    public class SessionState {
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And if you write your api in asp.net you can see sample below. Here, if I call `http://localhost:53148/api/auth?name=aa&psd=bb`， I'll get xml response, while I call it in login.js, I'll get json response.

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class AuthController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string name,string psd)
        {
            Product product = new Product
            {
                age = 18,
                name = "hello"
            };
            return Ok(product);  // Returns an OkNegotiatedContentResult
        }
    }

    public class Product {
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

App_start->webapiconfig.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors();
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried both of your suggestions and I'm still getting the same json error.

Comment: @NewbieCoder Good day sir, I think we can troubleshot it follow these steps: create a new asp.net core 3.1 mvc project and create a controller like what provided above, and replace the url in the login.js . If that worked, it means the issuse comes from your backend program, otherwise it comes from your react project.  If it worked with the newly created mvc project, you can then create a new controller in your own api project, and so on. To figuer out where the issue comes from and let's solve it. The sample code above is worked in a newly created react project and asp.net project.